# google-maps-react | Wont render, keeps at loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Im using google-maps-react, i followed the tutorial, and just tried to print a google map in my app, with the same structure as the example, but wont render

https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react

my console its totatlly clean btw...

here's my dir and files structure

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your own google maps api key in the .env file.